# What free HTML editors allow to embed table of contents into the HTML document?

Tags: windows, html, html-editor

I am looking for a free GUI editor on Windows that would generate a Table of contents in my existing HTML document based on header tags. It would have to tag all headers (H1..H6; no need to restrict levels) with ID's and create a section that contains links to all the headings (without affecting any other portions of the document/markup, so in terms of CSS hard-coded styling is preferred).

So far I tried Open Office Web/Writer and Visual Studio HTML designer, neither has that feature.

Comment: Thanks, Joe! Guesses might go wrong, so explicit statements are preferred here. Btw: I have such a thing as Javascript running in my browser (a UserScript adding a drop-down box containing the generated TOC as you describe it). If that's an option for you, let me know.